# How can I automatically get the groups corresponding to Administrators in a cygwin shell?

Tags: windows, users, group, cygwin

My regular user account is part of the Administrators Group.

When I start a cygwin shell using mintty, I don't get the group name corresponding to the Administrators Group in my set of groups. Here's the set of groups.

```
gid=197121(None) groups=197121(None),545(Users),4(INTERACTIVE),66049(CONSOLE LOGON),
11(Authenticated Users),15(This Organization),113(Local account),
66048(LOCAL),262154(NTLM Authentication),401408(Medium Mandatory Level)
```

When I start a cygwin shell using the "Run as Administrator" option, I get the group name corresponding to the Administrators Group in my set of groups. Here's the set of groups.

```
 gid=197121(None) groups=197121(None),114(Local account and member of Administrators group),
 544(Administrators),545(Users),4(INTERACTIVE),66049(CONSOLE LOGON),
 11(Authenticated Users),15(This Organization),113(Local account),
 66048(LOCAL),262154(NTLM Authentication),405504(High Mandatory Level)
```

Is there anything I can do to get the groups 114(Local account and member of Administrators group) and 544(Administrators) in my set of groups when I start a cygwin shell without using "Run as Administrator"?

Answer (score 1):

You *could* fake it by some tweak to the `/etc/passwd` file.  That possibility was mentioned on the [cygwin mailing list](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2016-03/msg00477.html) earlier this year:

```
Re: Change PS1 when run as administrator

    From: Corinna Vinschen <corinna-cygwin at cygwin dot com>
    To: cygwin at cygwin dot com
    Date: Wed, 23 Mar 2016 15:17:40 +0100
    Subject: Re: Change PS1 when run as administrator
    Authentication-results: sourceware.org; auth=none
    References: <F7CDFE45-BFA7-4599-B510-B40BCA19142F at etr-usa dot com> <28210846 dot 20160315202354 at yandex dot ru> <87mvpz1ong dot fsf at Rainer dot invalid> <0F37E0B7-A313-49F2-BAFD-59A7A144BD8C at etr-usa dot com> <loom dot 20160323T125711-592 at post dot gmane dot org>
    Reply-to: cygwin at cygwin dot com

On Mar 23 12:35, Brian Inglis wrote:
> Warren Young <wyml <at> etr-usa.com> writes:
> > On Mar 15, 2016, at 2:17 PM, Achim Gratz <Stromeko <at> nexgo.de> wrote:
> >> Andrey Repin writes:
> >>>    test $group -eq 114 && { x="#"; break; }
> >> Nope, that group membership isn't associated with real administrative
> >> powers.
> > Confirmed, at least on Win10 64-bit without any AD mucking things up.
> > That is, I get both 114 and 544 here, so I donât need the 114 rule at all.
> 
> Opposite for me on Win7 x64 non-domain machine! 
> I am always a member of 544(Administrators) group and it is my default
> primary group in normal non-admin and elevated admin shells. 
> 
> In elevated admin shell, I am also a member of 114(Local account and member
> of Administrators group) and 405504(High Mandatory Level) not 401408(Medium
> Mandatory Level). 
> 
> No idea how this works in domains and with domain accounts, but perhaps
> checking for 114 and/or 405504 would be more portable? 
> 
> $ uname -srvmo
> CYGWIN_NT-6.1 2.4.1(0.293/5/3) 2016-01-24 11:26 x86_64 Cygwin
> 
> normal non-admin shell:
> $ id
> uid=... gid=544(Administrators)
> groups=544(Administrators),197121(None),197610(HomeUsers),545(Users),
> 4(INTERACTIVE),66049(CONSOLE
> LOGON),11(Authenticated Users),15(This Organization),113(Local
> account),4095(CurrentSession),66048(LOCAL),262154(NTLM
> Authentication),401408(Medium Mandatory Level)

You have either some /etc/passwd, /etc/group settings overshadowing the
default settings, or you used the "desc" method described in
https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ntsec.html#ntsec-mapping-nsswitch-desc
to change your primary group.

Otherwise your primary group is always "None", or the equivalent in your
locale.  The admins group is *never* the primary group, unless you
messed with the settings for Cygwin as outlined above.

If you're member in the Admins group, then the admins group is part of
the non-elevated token, but only as "deny-only" group.  That means, it's
usually not shown in id, unless you made it primary group, in which case
it has to be shown.

You better remove this.  I think I'll fix this function to not allow
primary groups wehich are not enabled in the token.


Corinna

-- 
Corinna Vinschen                  Please, send mails regarding Cygwin to
Cygwin Maintainer                 cygwin AT cygwin DOT com
Red Hat
```

But it would have no effect on your ability to do administrative work in that shell.

Comment: I have spent couple of hours to digest the contents and tried to get the Administrators Groups in cygwin shell without success. Just letting you know that I did not just ask the question and disappear.

Comment: Corinna's comment is pretty comprehensive.  You might want to clarify your question to point out what you are trying to do (the group name by itself does not do much).

Comment: I must be missing something basic. I added the line `net user rsahu /comment: '<cygwin group="Users"/>'` to `/etc/nsswitch.conf` but that didn't change my default group ID. In addition, what I am looking for might not be possible. Corinna's comment *I think I'll fix this function to not allow primary groups which are not enabled in the token.* seems to indicate that it is not desirable either.